# Laravel API Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse empty array when expecting single object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

Why is it that from a unit test in Laravel if I do the following request, decode the json response, it comes back as an empty array:

```
$response = $this->get(route('api.inspections.get', [
    "id" => $inspection->id
]));

$apiInspection = $response->json(); # Empty array :(
```

Yet doing the most basic get request to that same URL gets me a nice json response.

```
$inspection = file_get_contents(route('api.inspections.get', [
    "id" => $inspection->id
]));
$inspection = json_decode($inspection); # The expected inspection stdClass
```

Thanks

---

**Edit: I found why this behaviour was happening.** 
It appears from the unit tests, Laravels implicit route model binding I was using fails. So although I thought it should be returning a json object (because it did from Postman) it was actually returning null because of what is presumably a bug in Laravel.

```
# So this api controller action works from CURL, Postman etc - but fails from the phpunit tests
public function getOne(InspectionsModel $inspection) {
    return $inspection;
}
```

So I had to change this to

```
public function getOne(Request $request) {
    return InspectionsModel::find($request->segment(3));
}
```

So I've wasted an hour on this simple task just because I thought "It clearly works, I can see it in Postman".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my edits, this is an issue with implicit route model binding not working from my unit tests. This is a known issue that isn't a "bug" as such, just not documented well:
[Can't test routes that use model binding (when using WithoutMiddleware trait)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16260)

Answer (score 1):

From the laravel docs on responses:

> The json method will automatically set the Content-Type header to
>   application/json, as well as convert the given array to JSON using the
>   json_encode PHP function:

```
return response()->json([
    'name' => 'Abigail',
    'state' => 'CA' ]);
```

Note the **given array** words, you are giving to the json() method an empty argument and you get that in return.

You can check here for some examples on how to test json api: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/http-tests

Comment: I'm basically asking how to extract the response body out of the response when the response is a TestResponse object. It works fine with CURL request, but Laravel's http client (presumably Guzzle?) is making it complicated.